# Basic Nginx rewrites

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

What would be the best equivalent to this Apache2 rewrite in nginx?

```
RewriteRule ^programmes/([A-Za-z0-9])? /index.php/programmes/?alpha=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I've tried the following but it doesn't seem correct (and doesn't work :P)...

```
location ~ ^programmes/([A-Za-z0-9])? {
    rewrite ^programmes/(.*)$  /index.php/programmes/?alpha=$1  break;
}
```

Any help would be gratefully received

Answer (score 0):

I think you're pretty close.  Try this, though I admit, I am shooting from the hip:

```
location ^~ /programmes/ {
   rewrite /programmes/(.+)$ /index.php/programmes/?alpha=$1 break;
}
```

Comment: Nope that doesn't appear to do it - to explain a little more about what I need to do I need to rewrite only when /programmes/ has something following it - e.g. /programmes/A - it doesn't feel like this should be a particularly difficult thing to do but I can't seem to get it to work in nginx - lol. It works fine like this in apache  (have also tried doing this without the location block with no joy. This rewrite is at the very top of my config, could it be possible that something lower-down is over-riding it? break does act like [L] in apache doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

by changing the rewrite to redirect, i was able to get this working

```
location ~ "programmes/(?<alpha>[A-Za-z0-9])?" {
  rewrite ^ index.php/programmes/?alpha=$alpha break;
}
```